# Scroll Viewer doesn't hide when not in use, sometimes (UWP/XAML)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, desktop

I'm using UWP, and the project have a page with a "StackPanel", that contains a "ScrollViewer".
The question is that scrol viewer doens't hide, when not in use (sometimes hide, but majority not).
Windows config to auto hide scroll bars is eneable.

The scroll viewer is setted to be "auto" visible on vertical, as the code below:

```
ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      x:Name="MainScrollViewer">
```

Can someone help me, please?

I tryed to change VerticalScrollMode to auto, but nothing changed to auto hide.
My guess is that i can't fix it on code, and maybe is a Windows control thing.
I tried to use scroll view with "auto" on a test application, and same thing happened.

Comment: Can the same behavior be reproduced using the [official code sample.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer?view=winrt-22621#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Place the stackPanel inside of the scrollViewer, opposed to the scrollviewer inside of the stack panel.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  x:Name="MainScrollViewer">
    <StackPanel Height="2000">
        
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This way the scrollviewer grows with the size of the stackpanel.